# Best way to concat two arrays in underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

What is the bes tway to get something like this:
ar1=[1,2,3,4,5]
ar2=[a,b,c,d,e]

ar3=[[1,a],[2,b],[3,c]]?

Comment: Why it's only till `3` and not full array?

Comment: what if the `ar1` and `ar2` have different number of values?

Comment: The length of both is always same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [_.zip](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) method.

`ar3 = _.zip(ar1,ar2)`

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like below by using `Array#map`,

```
var ar1=[1,2,3,4,5]; 
var ar2=['a','b','c','d','e'];
var ar3= ar1.map((itm, i) => [itm, ar2[i]]);
```

Comment: i am sure zip method is using your  answer only .

Comment: @Mahi Yeah under the hood, it uses the same. And it validates some additional checks also, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  ar2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  ar3 = [];

for (i = 0; i <= ar1.length - 1; i++) {
  ar3.push(new Array([ar1[i], ar2[i]]));
}

console.log(ar3);
```

Comment: This is entirely wrong as per the OP's requirement. OP wants to have array of arrays, But this would yield array of strings.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy got it bro and check it now